# Can I Install a Graphics Card While Windows is running?

Tags: graphics-card, display, hardware-detection

I built a new PC with an AMD Radeon Rx 480 4GB Graphics Card. The only way I could boot into BIOS and install Windows 10 was to remove the card from my motherboard and boot off of the (Intel i5 6600K) CPU's integrated graphics.

Now that the OS is running, I need to get the graphics card working. The only problem is that when the graphics card is in on the motherboard, it only outputs DVI signal. I have no DVI (input) monitors.

I've tried every combination of ports, monitors, and adapters I have. None of them work. Installing the graphics card before the computer boots up renders it unusable.

I tried installing the drivers before installing the card itself, but it gives me an error message because there isn't any AMD Radeon Graphics hardware detected.

Should I try to install the graphics card while the PC is running? Should I just get a DVI monitor? Are there any other solutions for this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think video cards are hotswappable. Also that only the DVI signal is output is strange since the reference card dosen't seem to have them . https://www.reddit.com/r/Amd/comments/4oiwjn/new_rx_480_doesnt_support_dvid_why/ for example

Comment: You should not work on internal components with the computer plugged in, let alone turned on. Have you checked the BIOS settings if there is an option to choose graphics controller?

Comment: How are you going to use that graphics card if you can't connect a monitor to it?

Comment: It's not a driver issue. Windows can send basic graphics instructions without knowing the precise drivers for that device. It's more a combination of a limited BIOS (make sure it's updated to current) and an odd DVI requirement from your graphics card. Personally, I'd find a DVI monitor to borrow, or return the card and get one that doesn't have this odd limitation.

Comment: I've also worked with discrete graphics cards before that only support sending BIOS and pre-Windows screens to specific ports, so that part isn't particularly surprising. But, they've always allowed full loading into Windows, and if I wasn't using a monitor on that port it would just be a matter of the first images on the screen being later in the Windows loading sequence (but still before the login screen).

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, no; you should never, ever install any hardware (inside the case) while your computer is turned on, let alone plugged in as this is a sure-fire way of damaging not only the component you're trying to install, but also every other component attached to your motherboard (and the MB itself).

That said, this is an extremely strange situation, and I can see why you'd want to know whether this is possible or not. As Journeyman Geek mentioned, this card doesn't have DVI outputs, and by default, the output shouldn't be switching to DVI-only.

This is just off the top of my head, and I have know way of knowing whether this will work or not, but have you considered manually installing the driver's .inf files directly, outside of the driver's exe package? Meaning, extracting the exe's contents using a program like 7zip, going through the folders, and looking for the correct .inf, right-clicking it, and selecting "Install?" Usually, by going this route, the device the driver is meant for doesn't have to be already installed for the driver to be accepted by Windows. This way, the driver is technically installed and Windows could therefore detect the device enough for you to have it connected and running in order for you to fully install the drive suite.

Comment: The card has a DVI output.

Comment: This answer is a bit fallacious.  Many devices are  capable of being added or removed inside running computers.  This is called hot swapping.  PCIe does support hot swapping.  However, in desktop PCs, this is largely unsupported.  You *should* be able to add or remove a graphics card without damaging your computer, however it might not work until a reboot,  if not supported.